# why I have 1 Miscellaneus Change - if I add Document Security Store

Tags: pdf, adobe, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pdfbox

I have signed document.  and I want to add DSS to my document.

```
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        File signedDocument = new File("/signed.pdf");
        File out = new File("/signed_plus_dss");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(signedDocument);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);

        int c;
        while ((c = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, c);
        }
        fis.close();
        fis = new FileInputStream(out);

        // load document
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(signedDocument);
        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
        COSDictionary catalogDictionary = catalog.getCOSDictionary();
        COSDictionary dssDictionary = new COSDictionary();

        /* ... I can add OCSP responses, and CRLS, and Certs here    
            in order to create document LTV, but now I don't need that. 
            I have another problem, not this... */


        /* if that's false, nothing happens */ 
        catalogDictionary.setNeedToBeUpdate(true);
        catalogDictionary.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("DSS"), dssDictionary);  

        /* ... if we add here Document level time stamp, everything is fine.
        signature will not be invalid with TSA. but it's invalid without TSA ... */  
        doc.saveIncremental(fis, fos);
```

that's it. everything is fine. when I see PDF Structure there is Document Security Store. but when I open PDF with adobe reader, my signature is invalid because - **"Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed."** and **"1 Miscellaneus Change(s)"**

but, something interesting happens here - if I add Pades-LTV (DSS + TSA), Everything works:

for example, if we add that codes:

```
        URL tsaURL = new URL(TSAUrl);
        PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE); 
        signature.setSubFilter(COSName.getPDFName("ETSI.RFC3161"));
        signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        TimestampeInt signatureInt = new TimestampeInt(tsaURL, null, null);
        doc.addSignature(signature, signatureInterface);
        doc.saveIncremental(fis, fos);
```

by the result, Document Level Time stump **works fine**. But I need **to add only DSS too** without TSA. how can I resolve that problem, what do you think?

sample documents: [First sample is - signature plus only DSS.  Second sample is signature plus DSS plus Document level time stump](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy3yk3hg66c1jh7/samples.rar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both in the originally signed document and in the document with DSS and Timestamp added, the **AcroForm** dictionary is a direct object in the **Catalog**, it is an indirect object in the document with only DSS added:

SIGN.pdf:

```
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
/AcroForm <<
/Fields [7 0 R]
/SigFlags 3
>>
>> 
endobj
```

SIGN+DSS.pdf:

```
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
/AcroForm 12 0 R
/DSS 13 0 R
>>
endobj
12 0 obj
<<
/Fields [7 0 R]
/SigFlags 3
>> 
endobj
```

SIGN+DSS+TSA.pdf:

```
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
/AcroForm <<
/Fields [7 0 R 12 0 R]
/SigFlags 3
>>
/DSS 13 0 R
>> 
endobj
```

While this is equivalent for the documents at hand, Adobe Reader might be befuddled by that.

I patched your SIGN+DSS.pdf to also have the **AcroForm** dictionary as a direct object in the **Catalog** here and Adobe Reader was happy...

[image: Difference in the patched SIGN+DSS.pdf version]

Comment: mkl. you are always great! 
p.s with editor do you use to see two document together in hex values (to see diferences)? I have Araxis Merge only.

Comment: @LadyBird I made that comparison using the Total Commander's compare function which can compare either as text or as binaries. Both these comparison modes are of interest in PDF analysis. But there surely are many other compare tools out there allowing the same.